# Is There A Better Way To Paste Sample Code?

Tags: support

Whenever I use the Code Sample tool to paste code I have to manually edit to add spaces to the beginning of most of the lines. I feel that I must doing something wrong. Can anyone advise me?

Comment: @ryanyuyu:  I doubt the OP isn't sure how to format their code; rather, they're looking for a better and more efficient way to go about it.

Comment: I've got it now. I was doing 1) click tool, 2) paste but instead I should 1) paste, 2) highlight, 3) click tool.

Comment: @Makoto Doesn't the Community entry mean the user accepted the duplicate?

Comment: (Aside: titles on Stack Overflow and on Meta tend to be sentence case these days. There's been something of a shift in style guides generally, which is that title case is thought to be rather formal).

Comment: In any editor Notepad++ for exemple, you can convert tab to space. so your code indent will be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste it in to the question/answer editor, highlight it all and click the code button.

[image]

Comment: Works like a champ! (Don't know why down vote) Thx. I'll accept as soon as 10 minutes expires.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to format your code *before* you paste it in, using whichever tool  you had written the code in the first place.  Most modern code editors come with the ability to format code; you would want to leverage that to get your code to be properly indented first.

Comment: The code is well formatted. The problem is that the outermost block usually begins on column 0.

Comment: If your code still has whitespaces in front of it when you paste it in, it can't realistically be well-formatted. Your editor's formatter would strip those whitespaces, which is what you'd want to leverage.